# Is it possible to serve files from Rackspace Cloudfiles from nginx?

Tags: nginx, rackspace-cloud

I'm storing a bunch of content in Rackspace's cloudfiles, and I need to serve that content to the client, but securely. It's not like these are super secret files, but putting them on a publicly accessible cdn would be unacceptable.

Right now I'm reading the files in my web framework and serving the contents as a response. I'd much rather return a response with an X-Accel-Redirect header.

The problem is you need an auth token that expires after 24 hours.

What are serverfault's thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using FUSE with the Cloud Files plugin? We've heard lots of success stories from this type of  configuration:

- Here's a good example of how to do it with Ubuntu:
  http://sandeepsidhu.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/mounting-cloud-files-using-cloudfuse-into-ubuntu-10-10-v2/
- and here's the CentOS version of the same doc:
  http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2137

I hope this helps!

Comment: CloudFuse feels really slow. I've tried this in other projects and the browser would still just hang.